# Nicotine stained panelling

Tags: painting, primer

I cleaned wood paneling with water and then with a magic eraser.   I rinsed the walls really well and the cloths were clean after rinsing & wiping the walls.  I primed walls with KILZ and now there is a stain showing through.   What should I do?

Comment: Use a better primer.  Check out my answer [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/165642/43874).  Kilz is a good general purpose primer, but some stains migrate and need a special solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you sand drywall to get rid of cigarette smoke?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/165639/can-you-sand-drywall-to-get-rid-of-cigarette-smoke) The answer there is great and addresses your concern brilliantly.

Comment: Here is [another question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/11901/43874) that shows knots in wood cabinets bleeding through paint.  It's the same principle, and the product recommended in the accepted answer is basically the same as the BIN primer that I recommended.

Comment: Was this KILZ Original (oil base) or KILZ 2 (latex base)?  Did you try a second coat?

Comment: Killz is pretty good stuff, especially the oil-based variety, but for something like that I think you need a shellac primer like BIN.

Comment: Shellac primer such as the premium one from sherwin Williams will cover even the worst smoke stains.  However for cleaning the smoke stains, windex is amazing!